# Semi-hierarchical SQL query with multiple tables and possible outer joins

Tags: sql, join, multiple-tables, hierarchical, libreoffice-base

I have products. Each product is made up of items and assemblies. Assemblies themselves can be made up of items too. So it's a hierarchy but limited in depth. What I would like to do is list products with the items and assemblies it contains, plus any items in the product's assemblies.

This is the output I would like to see. It doesn't have to look exactly like this, but the aim is to show the items in the product, then the assemblies and within each assembly the items with in it. The number of columns isn't fixed, if more are necessary to show the items in the assemblies there is no problem with that.

```
ProductID ProductName AssemblyID AssemblyName ItemID ItemName
--------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ------ --------
 P0001001 Product One
                                               I0045 Item A
                                               I0082 Item B
                          A00023 Assembly 1
                                               I0320 Item 1
                                               I0900 Item 2
                          A00024 Assembly 2
                                               I0877 Item 3
                                               I0900 Item 2
                                               I0042 Item 4
```

This I can then use to build a report grouped on the Product ID to list the contents of each product.

This is the table structure I have at the moment.

```
+ProductList-+             +ProductItems-+                                  
|ProductID   | ----------> |ProductID    |                                   +ItemList-+
|ProductName | \           |ItemID       | --------------------------------> |ItemID   |
|Price       |  \          +-------------+                                 > |ItemName |
+------------+   \                                                        /  |Cost     |
                  \    +ProductAssemblies-+                              /   +---------+
                   \-> |ProductID         |       +AssemblyItems-+      /
                   +-- |AssemblyID        | ----> |AssemblyID    |     /
                   |   |BuildTime         |       |ItemID        | ---/
                   |   +------------------+       +--------------+
                   |
                   |   +AssemblyList-+
                   +-> |AssemblyID   |
                       |AssemblyName |
                       +-------------+
```

What kind of SELECT statement would I need to do this.

I think I need some sort of outer join but I'm not totally up on SQL syntax to know how to structure the select statement. All my efforts have always led to the product being listed multiple times for each item and assembly. So if a product has 3 items and 2 assemblies, the product appears with 6 times.

Searching for this kind of problem is not easy as I don't know what I need to search on. Is it a three table problem, an outer join issue, or just a simple syntactical answer.

Or would it be better to switch to a pure hierarchical table structure without the use of assemblies? It would then be easier to search on hierarchical tables to solve any problems I might have.

I'm using LibreOffice 3.5.6.2 Base. It has wizards and other helpful things but they don't extend to the complexity of the situation that I find myself in. The aim is that the database contains prices and it can be used to properly price out the products from the cost of the items and time to build the assemblies.

Be gentle, I'm a newbie to SO.

Comment: Welcome on SO :) Your question is good, though it is usually a good pratice to show us what you have tried ;) I suggest you have a look to our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq as well. :)

Comment: I've tried stuff like the following SELECT "tblProductList"."ProductID", "tblProductItems"."ItemID", "tblProductAssemblies"."AssemblyID" FROM "tblProductList" LEFT JOIN "tblProductItems" ON ( "tblProductList"."ProductID" = "tblProductItems"."ProductID" ) LEFT JOIN "tblProductAssemblies" ON ( "tblProductList"."ProductID" = "tblProductAssemblies"."ProductID" ) but I just get each product repeated items*assemblies times (eg 3 assemblies x 5 items means I get a product repeated 15 times). I've tried left and right. As I say I don't know join syntax enough to do anything except with a single table.

Comment: You can edit your own post to add this information, just click on the "edit" link ;)

Answer (score 0):

The normal SQL approach to this would put all the data on one line, rather than split among several lines.  So, your data would look like:

```
ProductID ProductName AssemblyID AssemblyName ItemID ItemName
--------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ------ --------
 P0001001 Product One                          I0045 Item A
 P0001001 Product One                          I0045 Item B
 P0001001 Product One     A00023 Assembly 1    I0320 Item 1
 P0001001 Product One     A00023 Assembly 1    I0320 Item 2
 . . .
```

The product and assembly information, for instance, would not be blank for a given item.  All would be on the same line.

This information comes from two sources, the product items and the assembly items.  The following query gets each component, then unions them together, finally ordering the results by product:

```
select *
from ((select p.Productid, p.ProductName, NULL as AssemblyId, NULL as AssemblyName, il.Itemid, il.ItemName
       from Product p join
            ProductItems pi
            on p.productId = pi.ProductId join
            ItemList il
            on pi.ItemId = il.ItemId
      ) union all
      (select p.Productid, p.ProductName, al.AssemblyId, al.AssemblyName, il.Itemid, il.ItemName
       from Product p join
            ProductAssemblies pa
            on pa.ProductId = p.ProductId join
            AssemblyList al
            on pl.AssembyId = al.AssemblyId, join
            AssemblyItems ai
            on al.AssemblyItems join
            ItemList il
            on p.ItemId = il.ItemId
      )
     ) t
order by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Often, restructuring into the format you want would be done at the app level.  You can do it in SQL, but the best approach depends on the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll have a play with your example. Your explanation of how the query works is a great help in working out the different parts of the query.I'm using LibreOffice 3.5 so using it's report generation capabilities to produce the report.